# Personalized URL with pre-populated data

Tags: redirects, forms

I think I am going to use Google spreadsheets and an embedded form. I see that it is possible to pre-populate the fields with URL parameters. So I think I just need a way to redirect with the correct data from a database when a user goes to their Personalized URL.

I have no idea how to do the second part. Or if it is even the best way to do it.

**How do I set up Personalized URLS?**

**How do I redirect from those URLS to the spreadsheets?**

**Is this even the best method for pre-filled forms?**

Comment: Do you need more information or did Frank or Jase give you what you wanted?

Comment: Explain a bit better exactly what you're trying to accomplish and you'll get better quality answers.  I've re-read your question 3 times, and I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  As Frank said, the language your site is running on (if any) is pretty key.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it in Classic ASP.
Depending on your server you will have a scripting language that lets you talk to a database and then create a web page or a redirect.

In classic asp you would.
1. Get all your data from your DB, and store each item in a variable.
2. Build your url string mystring = "item1=" & varitem1 & "&item2=" varitem2 ....
3. Do a response.redirect to the url with a ? and the url string .

In essence what you are going to be doing is using a server side scripting language to create your url and then do a redirect.

Please let me know what your language is so that the forum can help you with a better sample